# Trigger update does not seem to finish

Tags: postgresql, performance, plpgsql, trigger, query-performance

I'm new to PostgreSQL triggers & functions and such.

I've got a table: `keywords` and each keyword should be unique. So when I try to insert a keyword that already exists, it should simply update the already existing keyword.

With the trigger below, inserting works fine, updating however takes very long - and I've always canceled it after a few minutes so I'm not sure what it would output.

Table: `keywords`

```
   Column   |            Type             |                       Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('keywords_id_seq'::regclass)
 keyword    | character varying(255)      | not null
 views      | integer                     | not null
 visits     | integer                     | not null
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null


CREATE FUNCTION update_if_exists() RETURNS trigger AS $keyword$ DECLARE result INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- Check whether the keyword already exists.
    result = (SELECT count(keyword) FROM keywords WHERE keyword = new.keyword);

    -- If we've got a match run an update statement.
    IF result = 1 THEN
        UPDATE keywords
        SET
            views       = views + new.views,
            visits      = visits + new.visits
        WHERE
            keyword     = new.keyword;

        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    RETURN new;
END; $keyword$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER id BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON keywords
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_if_exists();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You caused an **endless loop** by making the trigger `BEFORE INSERT` <strike>**`OR UPDATE`**</strike> . Use instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_if_exists()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$keyword$
BEGIN

-- Check whether the keyword alrady exists.
UPDATE keywords
SET    views  = views + NEW.views
      ,visits = visits + NEW.visits
WHERE  keyword = NEW.keyword;

IF FOUND THEN
   RETURN NULL;
ELSE
   RETURN NEW;
END IF;

END
$keyword$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER id BEFORE INSERT ON keywords     -- not OR UPDATE!
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_if_exists();
```

Comment: Wow, nice catch. There was no reason for me to even use the OR UPDATE, should have noticed this earlier. Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First question: Do you have an index on "keyword"?
Secondly: you could rewrite your trigger function like the following, which probably narrows the race condition window somewhat (there are much better solutions to solve the latter than this trigger function). I haven't tested this function, so please verify that it works if you choose to use it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_if_exists() RETURNS trigger AS $keyword$
DECLARE
    result          INTEGER;
BEGIN
    UPDATE keywords
    SET view = view + NEW.views,
        visits = visits + NEW.visits
    WHERE keyword = NEW.keyword;

    GET DIAGNOSTICS result = ROW_COUNT;

    IF (NOT result > 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO keywords (keyword, views, visits, created_at, updated_at)
        VALUES (NEW.keyword, NEW.views, NEW.visits, NEW.created_at, NEW.updated_at);

        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$keyword$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've just created the index, just been busy trying to figure out why the function didn't work as I thought it should. I'll try this out, would you recommend this function over the one @ErwinBrandstetter wrote?

Comment: Rule of thumb: If there is a choice between any answer and one by Erwin, choose Erwin's. So to answer your question, use his...

Comment: Alright. I appreciate your feedback and don't sell yourself short! :)